# Windows XP security settings for particular user

Tags: windows, security, settings, local, windows-xp

I have this scenario in one machine using Windows XP. I have three user accounts - admin, user1, user2 (I used to remote the pc via logmein). I set the local security settings to prompt users to change the password every 90 days. Now, is it possible that this message will only prompt to user1. The reason is that I want to manually change the password for admin and user2 whenever I want.

Any response from you guys with detailed ways on how to do this would be really really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably will have better luck with getting the appropriate answer for something like this on www.superuser.com - as its not really programming related.

Comment: Thanks In Sane for the link. I think I found the right answer. I'll just consult them next time. Users here are not just simple programmers they are brilliant in other aspects as well. =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming the password expiry policy is not a global policy administered from the domain the machine is joined, you can open the user management console (Right-click My Computer - Manage - User accounts - Local Users (or something like that - I don't remember, and don't have an XP)), then right click on the admin or user2 account and select Properties, and then check the Password never expires checkbox. This will mark the account from excluded from the local password expiration policy, and allow you to choose manually when to change the password (if ever).

Of course, you have to carefully consider the potential security ramifications of making such an exclusion.

Comment: Hi! Franci Penov. Thank you for your response. I think this answers my question. But I have to check first, if it's not a global policy. For the sake of everyone, here's how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

You should set "pssword never expire" flag for users which must not change the password corresponds to the general policy (every 90 days.

If youu need to do such changes per API I could write more about the details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe restall the system will solve your problem and you can have a try!